# What does no longer of this world mean?

Tags: meaning, spoken-english

**Example sentence**: but the ecstasy in which he lay drifting seemed that of a man no longer of this world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a definition of "this world" that seems to apply:
[Merriam-Webster "this world"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/this%20world)

> the world known to living men : the world of here and now

The dictionary contrasts that with "otherworld"

> : a world beyond death or beyond present reality

So, "no longer of this world" then means that the individual has lost connection to the here and now, to present reality.